# Aloe Vera leaf is broken

Tags: indoors, aloe

I have an Aloe Vera, which leaf became broken by this morning.

I do not know why this happened, or even what I should do with that leaf.

I admit that taking care of Aloe Vera is very hard (very sensitive, sunlight, temperature, watering, humidity), but as far as I know, I did everything well, as it was written in a lot of articles.

It does not seem underwatered, nor overwatered.

[image]

Here a closer image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My experience with Aloe Vera is that it is a very hardy plant. Being a succulent it likes a lot of sunlight and **very little** water. That bent leaf could be the result of the root system being limited to a tight pot, and so the plant is trying to grow big leaves with small roots. This sometimes happens after repotting. Simply cut that leaf close to the basis and you're good to go.

As a plus you'll have free Aloe vera lotion you can apply on your skin, ah!